# TimePicker null pointer exception when pressing buttons plus or minus

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, timepicker

The problem happens only when I try to force the layout to show the picker with increment and decrement buttons. So when I use this code in my fragment and press "+" or "-" the app crashes:

```
final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.cust_dialog); 
LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
```

If I comment the code line above, all work fine.
this is the cust_dialog:

```
<style name="cust_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></style>
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.TimePicker.updateInputState(TimePicker.java:580)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.TimePicker.access$000(TimePicker.java:56)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.TimePicker$2.onValueChange(TimePicker.java:150)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:1776)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java:1562)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.changeValueByOne(NumberPicker.java:1592)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.access$200(NumberPicker.java:90)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.widget.NumberPicker$1.onClick(NumberPicker.java:633)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-06 01:15:35.947: E/AndroidRuntime(19858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How Do I solve this?

Comment: What is the value of "inflater" before it crashes? You have a NullPointerException meaning something in those lines is null.

Comment: It's not null because the fragment with the TimePicker is correctly showed. It crashes only when I click on the "+" or "-" button of the TimePicker.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem yet?

Comment: Yes, I doesn't use anymore the old layout :D

Answer (score 4):

Add  tag within the timepicker. it works for me:

```
<TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker"     
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">  
 <requestFocus />  
</TimePicker>
```

Reference: http://blog.csdn.net/ljb_blog/article/details/9153435

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be unsolved yet and a known bug. 
In my case, when i clicked on EditText a nullPointer exception occured. My work-around was iterating through children until EditText was found and set it "focusable" property to false.

Recursively,

```
// level is just a counter for reading better Logs
private void hideFocusable(ViewGroup vg, int level)
{
    for(int i=0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) 
    {
        try
        {
            ViewGroup vt = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(i);
            Log.i("NODE",level+") "+ vg.getChildAt(i).getClass().getName()); 

            hideFocusable(vt, level+1);

        }catch (ClassCastException e) {
            View vf = (View) vg.getChildAt(i);

            Log.i("LEAF",level+") "+ vf.getClass().getName());

            // here you can pick EditText and setFocusable to false 
            if(vf.getClass().equals(EditText.class))
               vf.setFocusable(false);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on API level 19 (4.4) with NPE in TimePicker:695. The problem was that i set the onTimeChangedListener before setting 24HourView to true.

Wrong:

```
timePicker = (TimePicker) viewContent.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(listener);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Working:

```
timePicker = (TimePicker) viewContent.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(listener);
```

Comment: did you find any solution..I am facing the same issue but only after activity resumes.

Comment: I am using TimePicker and not TimePickerDialog.

Answer (score 0):

#### a) Changing the Style

I had to change the theme of my application to `android:Theme.Black` in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <application
        android:name="com.tunapui.news"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
```

add this style to styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black" />
```

The style of my fragment is different but now it works.

[image]

**Update:**

#### b) Using the property  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

i Think the problem is related with the focus when virtual keyboard is on screen, now without changing the style i add the property `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to my TimePicker,and works like a charm :).

```
  <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/toTimePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with

```
        timePicker.setSaveEnabled(false);
```